# Why do I always have to manually press "Enter Key" after every run in SPYDER?

Tags: python, ide, spyder

I am using spyder as my IDE for Python.

I notice that every time I

1. Select the code snippet
2. Press "F9"

as follows:

[image]

**I would have my console as follows:**

[image]

With all those `...`, I have to press "Enter Key" for many times to finish the execution.

I am really tired of doing so.

**How may I make it automatically finish everything?**

Comment: (*Spyder dev here*) What is your version? I think I fixed this bug a long time ago. Besides, in 2.2.3, we added the equivalent of Matlab cells (using the `#%%` separator), which will help you to run portions of a file more easily.

Comment: Another things is that this kind of operation runs much more smoothly if you use **IPython** instead of our provided Python console.

Comment: @CarlosCordoba   2.1.11 Many have recommended me spyder. Then as a newbie i just use it. IPython only has a command window right? I cannot view variables in IPython, right?

Comment: Ok, I can write my answer now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please update to Spyder **2.2.3**, it's much more stable and it'll fix your problem. For that just go to our [Downloads](http://code.google.com/p/spyderlib/downloads/list) page and use our Windows installer.

*Notes*:

1. Use `#%%` to separate file sections for evaluation (a la Matlab cells), instead of selecting every time the portion you want to send to the console.
2. Please install **IPython** to ease this task. IPython comes now not only with a command line interface but also with a graphical one which we embedded in Spyder to take advantage of its multiple facilities (like multine inputs) which in this case will let you evaluate file portions much more easily.

Comment: Thanks! But as a newbie I am a bit confused with all these software. THe spyder that I am currently using is installed together with python(x,y). I don;t reanlly understand what is the difference. See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18506195/directly-open-spyder-or-open-it-through-pythonxy/18512987

Comment: So in my case, should I uninstall my current spyder and pythonxy, and reinstall the new spyder? Also, for ipython, I am not sure I am suing the right one. Because my ipython interface is just a console, very user-unfriendly

Comment: I understand. The easiest way for you to update Spyder (and have IPython too) is this: a) Uninstall PythonXY; b) Download and install the latest PythonXY and c) Download spyder-2.2.3.win32.exe from our web page, run and install it.

Comment: Thanks!!! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18506195/directly-open-spyder-or-open-it-through-pythonxy