# Directly open Spyder or open it through Pythonxy?

Tags: python, spyder, pythonxy

Previously, I have been running Python in `Spyder`. I always started `Spyder` by directly double clicking its icon.

Today, I suddenly realize that I have another thing called `Python(x,y)`. I notice that I can also start `Spyder` through it.

**Do these two methods make any difference?
If not, what is the meaning of `Python(x,y)`? Does it have any other good features?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. **Python(x,y)**

   *Python(x,y)* is a *scientific Python distribution*. This means that it not only installs *Python* in your system but also the most important scientific packages needed for a scientist to be productive with the language.

   [These packages](http://code.google.com/p/pythonxy/wiki/StandardPlugins) are difficult to install by the user and also are too many to be installed one by one, so that's why *Python(x,y)* offers the possibility to install them all at once.
2. **Spyder**

   *Spyder* is one of the packages distributed by *Python(x,y)*, which offers a simple and convenient graphical environment to use the other scientific packages (like *numpy* or *matplotlib*). It resembles Matlab in its design.

Perhaps a comparison to *Matlab* is worth here:

1. *Matlab* is a huge program (about 5 gigs) that it's developed by one company and comes with a lot of packages and a graphical interface to use it.
2. *Python(x,y)* is also a big program (about 1 gig) but it's developed by two individuals who collect a lot of open source programs developed by a lot of different groups and institutions. It also comes with a graphical interface (*Spyder*) but there are others that fulfill a similar purpose (like the *IPython notebook*).

   So in the *Python* scientific world, every package is developed independently of each other and there is the need of a "meta" program (like *Python(x,y)*) that distributes them together.

Answer (score 1):

Actually i did not use spyder alone, but when you open it through Python(x,y) which is a scientific oriented distribution, some packages that are used in scientific/numeric computing automatically loaded.
Python(x,y) is based on python, Qt, spyder and includes many tools for scientific/numeric computation, visualizing (2D-3D), etc.
https://code.google.com/p/pythonxy/